# nextLine() not working after next() method

Tags: java, iterator, java.util.scanner

```
package new_package;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

public static void main ( String args[])

{
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter a character");

char c = input.next().charAt(0);

System.out.println ( "Enter a string");

String s = input.nextLine();

System.out.println (c);
System.out.println (s); 

}

}
```

The output of this program after first execution is :

Enter a character

And after i enter the character c in the output looks like:

Enter a character

c

Enter a string

c

The problem with this program is i am not allowed to input the string which is supposed to be input with the help of the next line commend .

The program automatically takes the value "" for the string and prints the vacant string.

Why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `nextLine()` after `next()`, to consume the end of the line that contained the token you got by calling `next()`. Otherwise, the end of the line is consumed when you call `String s = input.nextLine();`, which leaves `s` empty.

```
char c = input.next().charAt(0);
input.nextLine(); // add this
System.out.println ( "Enter a string");

String s = input.nextLine();
```